# Gives me the creeps

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language

Does 'gives me the creeps' mean that someone/something scares you? Or does it mean something more than just to be scared?

Answer (score 2):

To "give [somebody] the creeps" doesn't necessarily imply being scared as much as it implies unease. Think the [uncanny valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley), or feeling that there's some unspoken threat or tension in a situation.

If someone "gives you the creeps", it usually means you don't have any concrete evidence that they are a danger to you, but you feel uncomfortable around them, as if there is some unknown threat or danger.

Side note: to be idiomatic, one has to phrase it as "gives me the creeps" (ie. in the plural).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So we say it when we're uncomfortable or feel uneasy. If an old disfigured woman is staring at me for a long time can I say 'she gives me the creeps' even though I'm not scared since she's obvious old and weak and doesn't have any weapon on her?

Comment: @Ashraf that would be a perfect example of when this phrase might be used, yes!

Comment: Would it be wrong to use it when you're genuinely afraid of something?

Comment: @Ashraf It's also ok to use it if you're genuinely afraid of something, the phrase is mostly just agnostic of that rather than against it :-)